# Send parameters to php and get result in JSON

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-volley

I have code for send parameters to php and get result in JSON :

```
private void details_location(int id){

        HashMap<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
        parameter.put("id", id);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(parameter), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONArray respon=(JSONArray)response.get("location");

                    for (int i = 0; i < respon.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) respon.get(i);
                        id_location= person.getString("id_location");
                        address= person.getString("address");                   
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

and I have file php for proccessing query Mysql and have output in JSON :

```
<?php
    require_once('db_connect.php');
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $action="SELECT * FROM locaions WHERE id_location=\"$id\";";
        $query=mysqli_query($db_connect, $action);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
            $json['location']=array();
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $data=array();
                $data["id_location"]=$row["id_location"];
                $data["address"]=$row["address"];

                array_push($json['location'], $data);
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($db_connect);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
    else{
        $action="SELECT * FROM locaions WHERE id_location=4;";
        $query=mysqli_query($db_connect, $action);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
            $json['location']=array();
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $data=array();
                $data["id_location"]=$row["id_location"];
                $data["address"]=$row["address"];

                array_push($json['location'], $data);
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($db_connect);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }   
?>
```

when I run the program, the result always show location with `id_location=4` (statement else). Why `isset($_GET['id']) = false` ? How to send parameter to PHP and get result in JSON ?

Comment: To answer the question "Why isset($_GET['id']) is false" you should print the values that you receive as well as the URL you are trying to access, so you will understand better what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the code for sending parameters to ur php server**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                String parameter1 = (String) params[0];
                String parameter2 = (String) params[1];

                String link = "Mention ur url link here/parameter1+parameter1 +parameter2+parameter2+";

                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                in.close();
                return sb.toString();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

**On post Execute the php should return data in the json format and you can handle this data in post Execute**